# External Table Columns

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I have the following code. Now the issue is that we expect three columns in the file but sometime the other team sends us 4 columns. So instead of failing the load, it will load first three columns. When the file has less than 3 columns, then it fails which is expected. What logic do I need to place where it fails when an extra column is present in the file?

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING_DUMP (
"FIELD_1"            NUMBER,
"FIELD_2"            VARCHAR2(5),
"FIELD_3"            VARCHAR2(5)
)
ORGANIZATION external
(
TYPE oracle_loader
DEFAULT DIRECTORY MY_DIR
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET US7ASCII
  BADFILE "MY_DIR":"TEST.bad"
  LOGFILE "MY_DIR":"TEST.log"
  READSIZE 1048576
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|" LDRTRIM
  MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
  REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
  (
  "LOAD"               CHAR(1),
  "FIELD_1"            CHAR(5),
  "FIELD_2"            INTEGER EXTERNAL(5),
  "FIELD_3"            CHAR(5)
  )
  )
  location
  (
  'Test.xls'
  )
)REJECT LIMIT 0;
```

File Test.xls has sample content below. Second line is correct. It should fail for first line but it does not.

```
|11111|22222|33333|AAAAA
|22222|33333|44444|
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know how to do that in single step, so I'll suggest a workaround - see if it helps.

This is target table, which is - at the end - supposed to contain valid rows only:

```
SQL> create table ext_target
  2    (col1 number,
  3     col2 varchar2(5),
  4     col3 varchar2(5));

Table created.
```

External table contains only one column which will contain the whole row (i.e. no separate columns):

```
SQL> create table ext_dump
  2    (col  varchar2(100))
  3  organization external (
  4    type oracle_loader
  5    default directory ext_dir
  6    access parameters (
  7      records delimited by newline
  8      fields terminated by ','
  9      missing field values are null
 10      (
 11        col      char(100)    )
 12    )
 13    location ('test.txt')
 14  )
 15  reject limit unlimited;

Table created.
```

This is the whole file contents:

```
|11111|22222|33333|AAAAA
|22222|33333|44444|
|55555|66666|
```

External table contains the whole file (nothing is rejected):

```
SQL> select * from ext_dump;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|11111|22222|33333|AAAAA
|22222|33333|44444|
|55555|66666|
```

Insert only valid rows into the target table (so far, there are two conditions: there shouldn't be 4 "columns", and there can be only 4 `|` *separators*:

```
SQL> insert into ext_target (col1, col2, col3)
  2  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1),
  3         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2),
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3)
  5  from ext_dump
  6  where regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) is null
  7    and regexp_count(col, '\|') = 4;

1 row created.
```

The only valid row:

```
SQL> select * from ext_target;

      COL1 COL2  COL3
---------- ----- -----
     22222 33333 44444

SQL>
```

---

Now, you can adjust the `where` clause any way you want; what I posted is just an example.

Comment: It does not solve the issue at hand. I want to reject the load when I get more than 3 columns in a file which I won't know ahead of time.. I won't know if I get 4 or 20 columns. I want to reject the file. Not finding a fix yet without re-designing the whole thing.

Comment: "I want to reject the file" >> the **whole file**, not just offending records? Maybe you should then pre-process it (the file) at the operating system level, using programming language that is not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a fourth field definition that maps to a datatype sure to fail, like a date column with a funky format sure not to be seen? The "MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL" should render it NULL when not present, and the datatype conversion should error when it is present.

Comment: I won't know if I get 4 or 20 columns. I want to reject the file. Not finding a fix yet without re-designing the whole thing.

Comment: This would reject the file by failing on a record with a 4th field. Any additional fields wouldn't matter. Have you tried my suggestion?